# Google adsense reload the whole page on anchor clicks

Tags: jquery, tabs, reload, adsense

I have a website, where I have a tab based system.
The website has a page http://example.com/pageA.html

There are adsense units before and after the tabs.
Different tabs can be opened by clicking on them. They are jquery based tabs and are linked to content through anchor tags.

What I want to do is reload the whole page when an anchor tag is clicked in the tabs. Does google adsense allow this?

The whole page is only refreshed when the user clicks on another tab. The actual behaviour of the browser will not reload the whole page, but I want to reload the whole page. This means that all the ads will be reloaded as well. However, the content for all the tabs/anchor links is preloaded on the page and clicking on a tab would only reload the whole page with the new tab opened and reload the ads, but the content stays the same.

I also see this being done on ALEXA.COM, but does google adsense allow this?

Answer (score 0):

I think your going to have to rephrase your question a bit more. Cause I am reading that and trying to understand from it but the way your talking about one thing vs another makes no sense..

Adsense has nothing to do with how a page loads/works. Adsense is a PPC/PPV advertisement engine.

As to how the hash tags/anchors work thats dependent upon how the jquery or javascript reads the click, then does with it what its scripted to do. So with little to no code to show in regards to what you are trying to explain, as well as the explanation is hard to understand what your trying to imply its going to be hard to help you.

Comment: The actual behaviour of the browser will not reload the whole page when an anchor link is clicked. The content for all the tabs/anchor links is preloaded on the page and clicking on a tab would just change the tab. I want to reload the whole page with the new tab opened and reload the ads. http://domainsoutlook.com/s/site/stackoverflow.com.html#keyword_density_report would load the keyword density tab but when you go to other tabs the tabs opens without refreshing the page. I want the page to be refreshed each time another tab is clicked which also refreshes the ads.